# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') for swiper and next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

We upgraded to next.js 13 and now we get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

This is the stack trace:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at useState (/next/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1622:21)
    at file:///next/node_modules/swiper/react/swiper.js:26:51
    at renderWithHooks (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:7621:16)
    at renderForwardRef (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:7805:18)
    at renderElement (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:7985:11)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:8086:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:8058:14)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:7748:7)
    at renderElement (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:7919:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:8086:11)
error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at useState (/next/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1622:21)
    at file:///next/node_modules/swiper/react/swiper.js:26:51
    at renderWithHooks (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:7621:16)
    at renderForwardRef (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:7805:18)
    at renderElement (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:7985:11)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:8086:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:8058:14)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:7748:7)
    at renderElement (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:7919:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:8086:11) {
  page: '/'
}
```

And this is our `index.js` file:

```
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/css';

export default () => {
  return (
    <Swiper
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={3}
      onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
      onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
      ...
    </Swiper>
  );
};
```

And here's a link for a [Minimal Reproducible Example on GitHub](https://github.com/hosseinitabar/swiper-bug).

Simply clone and `npm install` and `npm run dev` and you should see the error.

How can we solve this issue?

Comment: there is a chance that this is caused by SSR, did you try to create a separate Swiper component and use `next/dynamic` with `ssr: false` to import it?

Comment: @mocherfaoui, no. To be honest I don't know what `next/dynamic` does. I need to read it first.

Comment: Must be some other issue with your app.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-qxb5iw?file=pages/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Comment next line in your next.config.js

```
experimental: { appDir: false },
```

Hope this helps